# AppleScript: How to add numbers in front of folder and sub folder name?

Tags: macos, applescript, directory

How to add numbers in front of folder and sub folder name?

I have my script here for a "Folder Maker" and I can add a number on the main folder but how does one keeps adding same number for all the folders and subfolders inside? Please help. Thank you.

```applescript
property structure : {"Contract Proposals", {"Contracts and proposals", {"Owner", "Architect", "Consultant", "General contractor"}, "Scope of work"}, "Existing Conditions", {"Base building information", "Owner provided drawing (can be CAD)", "Lease documents", "Building reports/environmental reports", "Surveys"}, "Programming", {"Questionnaires/spreadsheets", "Interviews/meeting minutes", "Adjacency matrix and diagrams"}, "Code-Permit", {"Approvals", "Zoning/building permit applications", "Permit documentation submitted", "Research section scanned", "Summary of code research", "Correspondence"}, "Design Sketches", {"Existing conditions (field verified)", {"Sk0"}, "Schematic design", {"Preliminaries", "Sk1 through x"}, "Design development", {"Sk1 thru x"}, "Renderings/presentations (dated)"}, "Construction Documentation", {"Construction documents (dated)", {"Sheet specs"}, "Specifications", "ComCheck/resCheck", "Supplemental drawings (dated)", {"Sd1 thru x"}, "Bulletins/addenda", "Design info/backgrounds (to/from consultants)"}, "Bidding", {"List of contractors", "Instructions to bidders", "Bids received", "Bid comparison"}, "Contract Administration (CA)", {"Payment approvals/bids", "Field notes/meeting minutes", "Pay applications", {"Incoming & reviewed"}, "Change order requests", {"Log", "Reviewed", "Approved"}, "Submittals", {"Log", "Submittals", "Reviewed submittals"}, "Request for info (RFI)", {"Log", "RFI's", "RFI responses"}}, "Close-Out", {"Punchlist", "Warranties", "Lien releases", "Certificate of occupancy", "Meeting minutes", "Meeting agendas", "Finished form of presentation (PDF or PPT)"}, "Product Info", {"Cut sheets", "Installation manuals", "Instruction manuals", "CAD block of fixture"}, "Cost Data", {"Cost estimates", "Cost analysis", "Bill of materials", "RSMeans information", "General contractor proposals/bids", "Vendor bids"}, "Communication", {"Email correspondence (dated)", "Meeting minutes (# and date)", "Client", {"Incoming", "Outgoing"}, "Contractor", {"Incoming", "Outgoing"}, "Consultant", {"Incoming", "Outgoing"}}}

set j_name to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Job Name:" default answer "job name")
repeat
    try
        set j_number to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Job Number:" default answer "0")
        if (j_number as integer) < 10000 and ¬
            (j_number as integer) > -1 then exit repeat
    on error errMess number errNum
        if errNum is -128 then error errMess number errNum
        display alert "Error" message "Project Number is not a number or is out of range."
    end try
end repeat
set j_number to text -5 thru -1 of ("0000" & j_number & " ")
set structure to {j_number & j_name} & {structure}
makeFolderStructure out of structure at (choose folder with prompt "Choose parent folder for structure")


to makeFolderStructure out of someItem at someFolder

  set currentParent to someFolder
  if class of someItem is not list then set someItem to {someItem}
  set completed to true
  repeat with anItem in someItem
    if class of anItem is list then
        makeFolderStructure out of anItem at currentParent
    else --  
        tell application "Finder" to try
            make new folder at someFolder with properties {name:(anItem as text)}
            set currentParent to result as alias
        on error errMess number errNum
            if errNum is -48 then
                set currentParent to ((someFolder as text) & (anItem as text)) as alias
            else
                set completed to false
            end if
        end try
    end if
  end repeat
  return completed
end makeFolderStructure
```

[What happens when I run my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwBke.jpg)

[What I would like to get when I run my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93SN6.jpg)

Comment: Your question is unfortunately not very clear.

Comment: @TGrif Its a hard problem to explain as understand it I have the J_NUMBER part and this is the number that becomes the Number in front of the name of the folder. I would like this number also appear in front of all the sub and sub sub folders. Does this make more sense ?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand - maybe provide a description or a diagram of what you want to start with and what you want to end up with so we can understand the process.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just added some images. I am sorry I dont know how to code at all.

Comment: So is the script supposed to create or add any files, or does it purely create the folder structure? Or does the folder structure already exist and the script is supposed to rename the sub-folders to include the job-number prefix part?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I am sorry i can see now why this is confusing. Script create folders only. I just need to do that with a number on all folders.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript is quite clunky for stuff like this, I would suggest `bash`. Save the following in a file in your `HOME` directory called `$HOME/go`.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the prefix number: " prefix
mkdir -p "$HOME/Desktop/Result"
cd "$HOME/Desktop/Result"
mkdir -p "${prefix}Bidding"
mkdir -p "${prefix}Close-Out"
mkdir -p "${prefix}Code-Permit"
```

Then start `Terminal` (type Command+Space and start typing `Terminal` till it guesses, then press `Enter`) and in `Terminal` type the following to make the script executable - press Return/Enter at the end:

```
chmod +x go
```

Then double-click `$HOME/go` in Finder and it will ask you the question and create the folders on your Desktop in a folder called `Result`.

It does not do everything you say, but you should be able to work it out from there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MarkSetchell, I understand the issues with apple script but using bash wont be an option for me either. If you I will keep trying to look for a applescript answer. Again thank you for trying.

Comment: @NikitaBeniaminov Would you care to say why you cannot use `bash` - there may be a work-around I can help with.

Comment: I just dont know anything about it. when you run my code it asks where i want the folder whats is the project name and then what the project number. Then it creates all the folders with in the folders, sub folders. I dont really know how to even start using bash but I can see that it will give me a number but the name and location needs to be entered manually in the code. I am sorry I am such a shmendrik. I just think if i could add figure out how to create one line in the Apple Script that would define the number of the folder and add it at line "make folder" it would be solved. thank you